# hide div (after a while) that was filled after ajax script was executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i am quite new to javascript.

What this example code does, is easy, I know.
Everything is working fine - at the end 'firstname' and 'lastname' is printed to the #status div.

Can anyone tell me how to fade that div after 5 seconds once it was filled through javascript?

This is my code:

**index.html**

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="ajax.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h3>Testpage</h3>
  First Name: <input id="fn" name="first_name" type="text">  <br><br>
  Last Name: <input id="ln" name="last_name" type="text"> <br><br>
  <input name="sbmt" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="ajax();">     <br><br>
  <div id="status"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**ajax.js**

```
function ajax_post(){
    var hreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "php.php";
    var fn = document.getElementById("fn").value;
    var ln = document.getElementById("ln").value;
    var vars = "fn="+fn+"&ln="+ln;
    hreq.open("POST", url, true);
    hreq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hreq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hreq.readyState == 4 && hreq.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hreq.responseText;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hreq.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
```

**php.php**

```
<?php 
echo 'Firstname: '. $_POST['fn'] . '<br>Lastname: ' . $_POST['ln'];
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setTimeOut function after firstname and lastname is printed like below

```
     setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("status").style.display='none' }, 5000);
```

Comment: Hi, Gunjan! This worked perfectly and is exactly I was looking for. Thanks a lot for ur help! =)